# insert data into MSSQL server using python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to insert data to the sql server table using following code,

```
import pyodbc
user='sa'
password='PC#1234'
database='climate'
port='1433'
TDS_Version='8.0'
server='192.168.1.103'
driver='FreeTDS'

   con_string='UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;PORT=%s;TDS=%s;SERVER=%s;driver=%s' % (user,password, database,port,TDS_Version,server,driver)
   cnxn=pyodbc.connect(con_string)
   cursor=cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES (%s,%s)",('thavasi','mumbai'))
   cnxn.commit()
```

Its giving me the following error while executing,

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql.py", line 26, in <module>
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES (%s,%s)",('thavasi','mumbai'))
 pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

I have checked the syntax for the insert statement its correct. So what causes this error?

Answer (score 11):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES (?,?)",('thavasi','mumbai'))
```

use **?** instead of **%** in pyodbc module

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) VALUES(?,?) ", (data1,data2))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works with SQL Server 2012 and later and integrated security

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                  r'Server=YourServer\YourInstance;'
                  'Database=YourDatabase;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;') #integrated security

cursor = conn.cursor()

SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO PY.PackageTables (PackageName,PackageTables) VALUES (?,?);") 
Values = ['Test1','Test3']

#Processing Query    
cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)

conn.commit()
print("Data Successfully Inserted")   
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `%` sign before the values also the `%s` must be in inverted commas

try this:

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES ("%s","%s")',% ('thavasi','mumbai'))

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a1 = row[0]
a2 = row[1]
valores = (a1, a2)

cursor2.execute('INSERT INTO [CENTRAL_ALARM].[dbo].[EEE](E3TimeStamp, CaptacaoSemAgua) VALUES (?,?)', valores)
```

Answer (score -1):

`string` formatting done here is wrong. Try this

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES (%s,%s)" %('thavasi','mumbai'))
```

Look into http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html

Answer (score -1):

If are using placeholders in a string, you need to use % operator in favor of using a parameterlist with ,. so your call should look like:

```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES (%s,%s)" %('thavasi','mumbai'))
```