# Insert data into sql after joining two excel data from python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I have joining data into **FinalData** variable.Now i want to inset that data into sql table.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas.io.sql
    import pyodbc
    server = 'Lppp-5CD812F42\SQLEXPRESS'
    db = 'HDb'
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + 
    ';Trusted_Connection=yes')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\neeraj.ya\\Xerox\\Python\\Address.xlsx')
    data1 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\neeraj.ya\\Xerox\\Python\\BAddress.xlsx')
   ##  Joining on data1 and data ##
    FinalData =data.join(data1, on='AddressID', how='inner', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
    print(FinalData)
    query1 = """
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pythtbl1] (
    AddressID varchar(255), 
    PostalCode varchar(255),    
    AddressTypeID varchar(255)     
    )"""
    query = """INSERT INTO [dbo].[pythtbl1] (AddressID, PostalCode, AddressTypeID) VALUES (?,?,?)"""    
    try:
    cursor.execute(query1)
    conn.commit()
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
    pass
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to insert FinalData  into sql table through python ? In finaldata i have joining data of two excel.

Comment: I am not familiar with Python but you will need a connection to the SQL server before you can execute any queries. Try Google.There are plenty of examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert data into MSSQL server using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589571/insert-data-into-mssql-server-using-python)

Comment: I got the solution:  try:
    cursor.execute(query1)
    conn.commit()
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
    pass
for india,data in FinalData.iterrows():# Dont remove India TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
    AddresID=data["AddressID"]
    PostalCod=data["PostalCode"]
    AddressTypeD=data["AddressTypeID"]    
    values=(AddresID,PostalCod,AddressTypeD)  
    cursor.execute(query, values)
conn.commit()
conn.close()

Answer (score 0):

**I got the solution.**

for loop

```
for india,data in FinalData.iterrows():
AddresID=data["AddressID"]
PostalCod=data["PostalCode"]
AddressTypeD=data["AddressTypeID"]
values=(AddresID,PostalCod,AddressTypeD)
cursor.execute(query, values)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```