# Post beanstalk queue data to Mssql using python script

Tags: python, sql-server, beanstalkd, openalpr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

Guys I'm currently developing an offline ALPR solution.

So far I've used OpenAlpr software running on Ubuntu. By using a python script I found on StackOverlFlow I'm able to read the beanstalk queue data (plate number & meta data) of the ALPR but I need to send this data from the beanstalk queue to a mssql database. Does anyone know how to export beanstalk queue data or JSON data to the database? The code below is for local-host, how do i modify it to automatically post data to the mssql database? The data in the beanstalk queue is in JSON format [key=value].

*The read & write csv was my addition to see if it can save the json data as csv on localdisk*

```
import beanstalkc
import json
from pprint import pprint

beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(host='localhost', port=11300)
TUBE_NAME='alprd'
text_file = open('output.csv', 'w')

# For diagnostics, print out a list of all the tubes available in Beanstalk.
print beanstalk.tubes()

# For diagnostics, print the number of items on the current alprd queue.
try:
    pprint(beanstalk.stats_tube(TUBE_NAME))
except beanstalkc.CommandFailed:
    print "Tube doesn't exist"

# Watch the "alprd" tube; this is where the plate data is.
beanstalk.watch(TUBE_NAME)


while True:

    # Wait for a second to get a job. If there is a job, process it and delete it from the queue.
    # If not, return to sleep.
    job = beanstalk.reserve(timeout=5000)
    if job is None:
        print "No plates yet"
    else:
        plates_info = json.loads(job.body)
    # Do something with this data (e.g., match a list, open a gate, etc.).
    # if 'data_type' not in plates_info:
        # print "This shouldn't be here... all OpenALPR data should have a data_type"
    # if plates_info['data_type'] == 'alpr_results':
        # print "Found an individual plate result!"
    if plates_info['data_type'] == 'alpr_group':
        print "Found a group result!"
        print '\tBest plate: {} ({:.2f}% confidence)'.format(
            plates_info['candidates'][0]['plate'], 
            plates_info['candidates'][0]['confidence'])
        make_model = plates_info['vehicle']['make_model'][0]['name']
        print '\tVehicle information: {} {} {}'.format(
            plates_info['vehicle']['year'][0]['name'],
            plates_info['vehicle']['color'][0]['name'],
            ' '.join([word.capitalize() for word in make_model.split('_')]))
    elif plates_info['data_type'] == 'heartbeat':
        print "Received a heartbeat"
        text_file.write('Best plate')
    # Delete the job from the queue when it is processed.

job.delete()
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589571/insert-data-into-mssql-server-using-python help you?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to directly export data from beanstalkd.

- What you have makes sense, that is streaming data out of a tube into a flat file or performing a insert into the DB directly
- Given the IOPS beanstalkd can be produced, it might still be a reasonable solution (depends on what performance you are expecting)

Try asking https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/beanstalk-talk as well